# How to search for links on one web site to another

Tags: google-search, search, search-engine, search-operators

Is there a way, to use Google Search to search for all links to a particular website on a different website. For example, could I search for all links to Wikipedia on this site (webapps.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Related: [Find deep links to our site with Google Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8811/88163), [How to search for all outbound links of a particular website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170891/88163)

Answer (score 1):

"wikipedia.org" site:webapps.stackexchange.com
link: is dead since 2017

> Find pages linking to a specific domain or URL. Google killed this operator in 2017, but it does still show some results—they likely aren’t particularly accurate though. (Deprecated in 2017)

[G operators ahrefs.com](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/)