# Find deep links to our site with Google Search

Tags: google-search, search-operators

We are in the process of moving to a different provider, and I want to check which popular deep links go to our site. I have some server logs, but I want to cross-check with Google. I do know

```
link:ourdomain.com
```

Can I exclude links that go directly to `ourdomain.com` or `www.ourdomain.com` from this search?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete as the link: search operator is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) you can get a more comprehensive view of the inbound links. You can also download the table of links to a CSV file, which you can then massage in a spreadsheet program to your heart's content.