# How to search for all outbound links of a particular website?

Tags: google-search, search, links, github-pages

I want to search for all outgoing links with the URL `https://github.com` from this link `https://whatevery1says.github.io/we1s-templates/creating-a-project/`. I can do that with [Outbound Links Checker Tool](https://www.searchenginegenie.com/tools/chkOutboundLinks.php), but is there a way to do that with Google Search only? I try this query:

`site:https://whatevery1says.github.io/we1s-templates/creating-a-project/ inurl:github`

But it doesn't match any documents. However according to the aforementioned tool, there are:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### site:

The `site` tag restricts your search results to a particular website and the correct usage would be `site:whatevery1says.github.io`

### inurl:

The `inurl` tag restricts search results to those URLs that include a specified word.  Since the word `github` already forms part of the `site` address, the addition of `inurl:github` is redundant (changes nothing).

### Google Search Results

Google searches a huge index of web pages in an effort to return **pages** that meet your search criteria, in order of relevance.  Tags are a tool used to help focus that search.

### Outbound Links

You are trying to get Google to search through one specific page's indexed content and return a list of any URLs it contains, filtered for the term you provide.  **This will not work.**